# /signalr/hubs 404 (Not Found) in DNN 7.3.4

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am developing a website using DNN 7.3.4. I am signalr in this.
I have executed this script for `AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx`.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dnn_hostsettings WHERE SettingName = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx' )

      insert into dnn_hostsettings
        (SettingName
        , SettingValue
        , SettingIsSecure 
        , CreatedByUserId
        , CreatedOnDate
        , LastModifiedByUserId
        , LastModifiedOnDate
        )
        values(
        'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx'
        ,'/DesktopModules/|/Providers|/LinkClick\.aspx|/SignalR'
        , 0
        , -1
        , GETDATE()
        , -1
        , GETDATE()
        )

    GO

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dnn_hostsettings WHERE SettingName = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx' and SettingValue not like '%/signalr%' )

    update dnn_hostsettings
        set settingValue = (select settingValue + '|/signalr' from dnn_hostsettings where settingname = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx')
    where settingname = 'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx'

    GO
```

And in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>

var objHub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    //....
})
```

But it's not working every time it's showing this.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After huge R&D I found this

My `owin startup class` was not starting. I already have these keys in web config for automatically start `owin`

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="MyNamespace.MyStartupClass" />
```

But `owin startup class` was not starting after doing this.

Then I found `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` is responsible for starting `owin startup class`. And I missed to add this `dll` in my project. After adding `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` `owin` started and register hub routes successfully.

Comment: For me, the problem was this and after copying that dll the problem fade away.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the OwinStartup class that starts the signalR hub in your application.  Look at this project on my github called [DnnLogAnalyzer](https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnLogAnalyzer).  I have a class called [Startup.cs](https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnLogAnalyzer/blob/master/Components/SignalR/Startup.cs) that hooks into the OwinStartup and starts the signalR hub for the application.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DotNetNuclear.Modules.LogAnalyzer.Components.Startup))]

namespace DotNetNuclear.Modules.LogAnalyzer.Components
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ...
            app.MapSignalR();
        } 
    }
}
```

If you are a DNNHero.com subscriber, you can also check out my step-by-step tutorial for tips on getting [SignalR working in your DNN application](https://www.dnnhero.com/video/configure-signalr).

Comment: I have already added startup class and in web config i have these keys for automatic owin startup
`<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
   <add key="owin:appStartup" value="MyNamespace.MyStartupClass" />`